# Changing the custom-attrs.xsl file in DITA did not change my background-color of table column headers. how do I change it, then?

Tags: background-color, dita, dita-ot

I expected that changing the `trgoup.thead` element in `custom-attrs.xsl` with `background-color` would change the table column head background color.

But the background of the table column heads did not change. I put the file in both `fo/xsl/` and `attrs/`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So an XSLT customization stylesheeet with an xsl:attribute like this should work:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="tgroup.thead">
  <xsl:attribute name="background-color">yellow</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

If you are using a PDF customization folder to provide the XSLT there is an "catalog.xml.orig" catalog file which needs to be renamed to "catalog.xml" and inside it you should uncomment this mapping:

then add a "custom.xsl" stylesheet in the "Customization/fo/attrs" folder with your custom XSLT overrides.

https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/pdf-plugin-structure.html